# Selenium Data Driven Testing in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, data-driven-tests, data-driven

How to do data-driven testing in selenium with python, and in what kind of case do we need to data-driven test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pytest` library something as below code demonstrates.

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("num1, num2, output", [(10, 2, 5), (20, 10, 2)])
def testDivisionWithPositiveValues(CreateCalculatorClassObj, num1, num2, output):
    result = CreateCalculatorClassObj.Division(num1, num2)
    assert result == output
```

In the above code `@pytest.mark.parametrize` is from `pytest` library and it is used where you want to pass the data to the method. The mothod annotated with this annotation will automatically pick the data from it.